# Cannot access ES on localhost:9200

Tags: php, elasticsearch, installation, xampp, config

So i'm trying to setup Elastic Search with xampp, I have installed elastic search from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html), which comes with JDK. I have also set SSL to false in my `elasticsearch.yml` config file.

my config looks like this:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically      
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 15-04-2022 16:08:51
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false     <----- I MODIFIED THIS
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["MENT-PLAN-L560"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from localhost and local networks
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: [_local_, _site_]

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from localhost and local networks
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: [_local_, _site_]

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

I did this because otherwise I couldn't connect to `127.0.0.1:9200`. Now, the problem is, it promps me with a username and password form and I know the default username is `elastic` although I don't know the password because it is stored in the cluster.

So I tried resetting the password by running the command: `elasticsearch-reset-password.bat -u elastic -i`

But i get this:
[image]

I also tried forcing the command `elasticsearch-reset-password.bat -u elastic -i -f` but since my cluster is unhealthy for whatever reason, it fails after I put the password. What am I missing?

Comment: did you check that the 9200 port is open? netstat -anpl | grep 9200. you didnt share any log that we could help you.

Comment: yes, it's open. I ended up messing with the config file a little more and got it running but now I have issues running kibana.